# bundle.js:2 ReferenceError: Collection is not defined at bundle.js:2:488700

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, webpack, reference

I am learning to build a basic web app using React and Webpack. I run `npm start` and a blank webpage appears. When I inspect it, I can see the error

```
bundle.js:2 ReferenceError: Collection is not defined
    at bundle.js:2:488700
    at Mu (bun...
```

I tried deleting and running `npm run build` again to create a new bundle.js file but the same if not worse errors come up. (I am also using Google firebase for data). If someone could help me that could be great.
Here is how I have structured it:

[image]

Here is my:

**webpack.config.js**

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',

output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public', 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  devServer: {
    static: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    port: 3000,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

**App.js**

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import db from './firebase';
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';


function App() {
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    const q = Collection(db, 'messages');
    const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
      const data = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
        id: doc.id,
        ...doc.data(),
      }));
      setMessages(data);
    });

    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);

  const sendMessage = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (inputValue.trim() !== '') {
      await addDoc(Collection(db, 'messages'), {
        text: inputValue,
        createdAt: Date.now(),
      });
      setInputValue('');
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Messages</h1>
      {messages.map((message) => (
        <p key={message.id}>{message.text}</p>
      ))}
      <form onSubmit={sendMessage}>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={inputValue}
          onChange={(e) => setInputValue(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button type="submit">Send</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Communications Platform</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="/dist/bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**package.json**

```js
{
  "name": "communications-platform",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A simple communications platform built with React and Firebase",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "communications",
    "platform",
    "react",
    "firebase"
  ],
  "author": "Your Name",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^9.18.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-firebase-hooks": "^5.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.16.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.16.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.3",
    "webpack": "^5.64.4",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.7.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Updated App.js with the following code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import db from './firebase';
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';
import { collection, onSnapshot, addDoc } from 'firebase/firestore';
```

I changed the uppercase 'C' in Collection to lowercase in:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const q = collection(db, 'messages');
    const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
```

and:

```
 if (inputValue.trim() !== '') {
      await addDoc(collection(db, 'messages'), {
        text: inputValue,
```

And it started working :).